# Kubernetes elasticsearch's secret .p12 incode base64

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I use the elasticsearch secret function in the kubernetes environment.
There is a problem with the distribution of certificates used at this time.
I use a *.p12* format certificate, which Elasticsearch uses by default. For use https, all PODs need to use Kubernetes secrets to share certificates.
But,
`kubectl create secret generic db-user-pass --from-file=./username.txt --from-file=./password.txt`

I can not use the command like above, and I need to generate secrets with a .yaml file.
However, if I create a *.yaml* file, it will not be base64 encoded. How can I solve it?

Finally, I want to know how to write *.yaml* ?
The example below does not work.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
  name: my-certificates
  namespace: nms
type: Opaque
files: 
  - my-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create secret like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
  name: my-certificates
  namespace: nms
type: Opaque
data:
  username: YWRtaW4=
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

with proper username and pasword.

Execute command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f your-secret.yaml
```

Reboot Node VM.

Then you can decode the password field:

```
$ echo 'MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm' | base64 --decode
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
kubectl create secret generic db-user-pass --from-file=./username.txt --from-file=./password.txt
```

Works very similarly to creating secrets using manifest files (e.g. yaml or json files). `kubectl` will create the object using the specified parameters, and you can use the following command to get the raw manifest file:

```
kubectl get secret -o yaml db-user-pass
```

Looking on `kubectl` docs:

```
      --from-file=[]: Key files can be specified using their file path, in which case a default name will be given to
them, or optionally with a name and file path, in which case the given name will be used.  Specifying a directory will
iterate each named file in the directory that is a valid secret key.
```

You can do the same with your p12 file and it should just work, maybe the secret name will not be what you want.
You can try doing something like:

```
cat > cert.yaml <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
  name: my-certificates
  namespace: nms
type: Opaque
data:
  tls: $(cat ca.p12 | base64 | tr -d '\n')
EOF
```

Also, notice that you might need a different secret type, so it's best to consult the elastic search docs.

One final note: as you noticed, the secrets are base64 encoded in the manifest files - which makes it really insecure to store them on source control (or anywhere else, actually). There are a few good solutions for creating encrypted secrets that can be persisted to source control, you can read more about it [in this post](https://blog.solutotlv.com/can-kubernetes-keep-a-secret/).